# How to change background color for a CheckList widget from tkinter.tix module?

Tags: python, tkinter, background, widget, tix

I tried to google it but couldn't find out. I am trying to create a CheckList widget with a tkinter.tix package in Python3.5 and set background color to white with this code:

```
from tkinter import tix as tk
checklist = tk.CheckList(parent, browsecmd=br, width=650)
checklist.tk_setPalette(background="white")
```

Unluckily all of the widgets on the screen got white background.

I have tried

```
checklist = tk.CheckList(parent, browsecmd=br, width=650, background="white")
```

but it seems not to have any effect on the background of CheckList

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify background option afterwards declaration with **.config** function of the CheckList.
In particular:

```
checklist=tk.CheckList()
checklist.pack()
checklist.config(bg='blue')
```

Most of the tkinter widget are likely to work in that way...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a year late but I found the answer:

`checklist.hlist.config(bg='white')`

is what you need.